# Dropbox integration shows error at run time

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am integrating dropbox API with my android project,for that I downloaded android SDK from [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android) link and also another example project from [this](https://github.com/mjlim/dropbox-android-sync-sdk/tree/master/examples) link.While integrating both example codes in my project shows error at run time.I searched many solution in internet but unfortunately it wouldn't make my code error free.

This is my console screen

```
[2014-05-10 09:37:43 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity;
[2014-05-10 09:37:43 - ExampleDropboxApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity;
```

So any one please do a needful to me.

[image]

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your project directory structure including the files? It looks like you have the SDK library linked twice (e.g. in different versions) or something similar.

Comment: @Philipp I uploaded directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the inside two Dropbox API jar files both have the class

```
com/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity.
```

The simple way is to remove one of them from one of jar file. You can use 7z or programs to remove them.

Here's a screen shot of the files you might need to remove in that jar file

[image: AuthActivity]

Comment: Specifically, it looks like both the Core SDK and Sync SDK are being included in the same project.

Comment: @user3639161 When I remove `dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar` this jar from my project it shows `cannot be resolved to a type` error in  `DBRoulette.java,DownloadRandomPicture.java,UploadPicture.java` java files. As like same when I remove `dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar` this jar which shows same error in 
`HelloDropboxActivity.java` java file.

Comment: Its what smarx mentioned. In the two jar files
dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar
dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar 
You will see two similar folder directories that have com/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity. Delete one of them in the jar file and that will resolve the conflict that the compiler is erroring about. This is because the ant build doesn't know which class to use.

Comment: I can't generate `jar` from expanded `.class` files after removed the `Lcom/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity.class` file

Comment: Just use a zip program and zip them back into a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem few days back. I am mentioning below what Worked for me.

- *Right Click* on your **Project Name**
- *Click* on **Build Path**
- Goto **Configure Build Path**
- Goto tab **Order and Export** in Java Build Path
- *Uncheck* your **.jar** Library.

Do let me know if this work for you :)

Comment: It shows no error in console but when I click project button for performing my task it shows `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 10:36:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(680): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

Comment: Why you have added Android.jar while android-support-v4 is already present in lib.
http://i.imgur.com/jCFVnKt.png

Comment: I unchecked that Android.jar in Java Build Path

Comment: ya as like same what I mentioned in previous comment

Comment: are you using anyother library like ActionBarSherlock etc which needs to be imported in the project explorer as a project?

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution should be to:

1. Open both jar files; dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar and
   dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar
2. Delete the client2 folder in the former sdk and replace it with
   client2 from the latter
3. Then download a copy of json_simple-1.1.jar.
4. Copy json_simple-1.1.jar and dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar into your
   libs folder and include these two in your project properties; this
   will help to avoid future errors

NB: You don't need to include dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar anywhere.